# Makefile passing variables to bash script

Tags: bash, makefile

I'd like to pass a space-delimited string of quoted substrings to a `make` target (actually, several different `make` targets) from a Makefile. The target just executes a bash script, that will then pass each quoted substring as a positional argument to another script.

Test `Makefile`:

```
FOO="foo bar"
FOO+="bar baz"
FOO+="baz qux"
FOO+="qux"
export FOO

t:
    ./script.sh
```

Here's `script.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -ex

./thing.sh "$FOO"
```

This doesn't work; the output (note the surrounding single quotes) is:

```
 ~/c/scrap
(i) make t
./script.sh
+ ./thing.sh '"foo bar" "bar baz" "baz qux" "qux"'
```

To be clear, what I would like is to pass many arguments to `thing.sh` instead of a single argument, and I need to quote each argument, since it may have spaces or special characters.

```
 ~/c/scrap
(i) make t
./script.sh
+ ./thing.sh "foo bar" "bar baz" "baz qux" "qux"
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Ideally we would solve this in `Makefile` to avoid duplicating the solution in each target that consumes `FOO`.

Comment: I did not realize you need to preserve the double quotes.

Comment: Do any of your 'words' in double quotes contain spaces or other special characters?  Are you sure `script.sh` (and `thing.sh`) need the quotes, or do you simply want it run as if you typed it at the console with quotes around each word.  The difference is whether the value of `$1` in `script.sh` should be `"foo"` or just `foo`?

Comment: Yes, they contain spaces and thus need to be quoted; sorry I didn't clarify this in the initial example. (It is clarified in my proposed solution though.) I'll edit the question to reflect requirements more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, that solves the issue at the Makefile level:

```
FOO="foo bar"
FOO+="bar baz"
FOO+="baz qux"
FOO+="qux"
export FOO

t:
    eval './script.sh $(FOO)'
```

Here's `script.sh`.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -ex

./thing.sh "$@"
```

Here's `thing.sh`.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
echo "$4"
```

Output:

```
 ~/c/scrap
(i) make t
eval './script.sh "foo bar" "bar baz" "baz qux" "qux"'
+ ./thing.sh 'foo bar' 'bar baz' 'baz qux' qux
foo bar
bar baz
baz qux
qux
```

Comment: What's the point of the `eval`? `./script.sh $(FOO)` will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: I believe the point of `eval` is to pass many arguments to `script.sh` instead of a single string.

Comment: It makes no difference. `eval 'whatever'` and `whatever` do the same thing. That is the *definition* of `eval`: it executes its argument as if it were a shell command.